# Grails multiple pages form submit

Tags: grails, grails-2.0

I am using Grails for my project.

There will be a lot of forms across multiple pages and using next and previous to navigate.

Also need to provide the function of save as a draft.

Are there any good way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grails provide [webflows](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Plug-ins/web%20flow.html) to make this kind of form wizards. There's also a detailed guide about this in the [documentation](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/single.html#webflow). Example:

```
class BookController {
   …
   def shoppingCartFlow ={
       showCart {
           on("checkout").to "enterPersonalDetails"
           on("continueShopping").to "displayCatalogue"
       }
       …
       displayCatalogue {
           redirect(controller: "catalogue", action: "show")
       }
       displayInvoice()
   }
}
```

Here you have a flow with 3 steps: showCart, displayCatalogue and displayInvoice. You can store objects that will live in the entire flow without beign persisted in the database yet.

Comment: Be aware: The web flows plug-in does not work [with mongoDB GORM in standalone configuration](https://jira.grails.org/browse/GPWEBFLOW-102), [with hibernate 4](https://jira.grails.org/browse/GPWEBFLOW-93) and has a [ratio of open to closed bugs of 93% to 7%](https://jira.grails.org/browse/GPWEBFLOW/?selectedTab=com.atlassian.jira.jira-projects-plugin:issues-panel) as of the time of this writing. That being said: it is a side project, and [Graeme Rocher has a lot to do](https://jira.grails.org/secure/ViewProfile.jspa?name=graemerocher).